# Execute a command for all files in a folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I want to run a command on all files in a directory.
    For %%1 in (c\conversion*.ajt) do *convert command* %%1 %%2
However I need to have an output filename the same as the input but with a different file extension.

```
asciitojt.exe filename1.ajt filename1.jt 
asciitojt.exe filename2.ajt filename2.jt 
asciitojt.exe filename3.ajt filename3.jt
```

is what I want to get out of the system.
How do I replace the last 3 characters?
This is to run in a batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for %%i in (*.ajt) do "asciitojt.exe" "%%~i" "%%~ni.jt"
```

Start in the folder with the *.ajt files.